# How to open detail section below grid element (CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, styling

I have a list of squared items displayed in a grid. When I click on one of the items, I want to display a section below it that takes the full width of the parent container.

Images for clarity:

1. [Collapsed grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vYmQ.png)
2. [With expanded section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8iuv.png) (the content will change depending on the item selected, but the size will be the same)

Simplified code:

```
const MyItems = () => {

   const Item = (props) => {
      return (
         // squared item
      )
   }
   return (
      <div className="container">
         {itemList.map((item, index) => (
            <Item key={index} {...item} />
          ))}
      </div>
   )
}
```

Styling of div container:

```
   flex: 1;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
   grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, auto);
   grid-gap: 1rem;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
```

**What I tried**:

I tried adding another container below the item, like so

```
      <div className="container">
         {itemList.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
               <Item {...item} />
               <div className="expanded-section">
                  // content
               </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
```

and added `width: 100%` and `height: 300px` to the expanded container but of course the width is limited by the grid item and won't take the width of the parent, [so this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5nXh.png).

How can I achieve [my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8iuv.png) using just CSS, if possible?